# Why are methods in class that extends Abstract class running even when not called?

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract-class, extends

Consider the following:

```
public class OuterClass {
    static class NestedClass extends AbstractList<List<Integer>> {
        void add(/* parameters here */) {
            // note this method is not declared public
            // print here does NOT appear in output
            // implementation details here
        }

        public int size() {
            // print here appears in output
            // implementation details here
        }

        public List<Integer> get(int index) {
            // print here appears in output
            // implementation details here            
        }
    }

     public static List<List<Integer>> method(/* parameters here */) {
         NestedClass nc = new NestedClass();
         nc.add(..);
     }
}
```

Then in a separate method, I create an instance of `NestedClass`. When I run the code, without ever invoking `get` or `size`, the print statements appear in output. How/why does this happen?  I understand that `get` and `size` are necessary since `AbstractList` is extended, but I am never invoking `size` or `get`.

In general, if `B` extends `A`, will any call to a method of `B` inherently invoke the overridden abstract methods implemented in `B`?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show that piece of code?

Comment: Maybe `AbstractList` is calling them

Comment: @AisforAmbition right off the bat, looking at the source code for `AbstractList`, there is an immediate call to `size()`: [AbstractList](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/AbstractList.java#108). So if you are calling `super.add`, thats the reason why. Similarly, other methods may do the same.

Comment: That makes sense why print statements show up then. Can you share where you found this info? I googled all over and didn't find anything. Is it just in javadocs?

Comment: I commonly use [grepcode.com](http://grepcode.com/) to view the source files of Java libraries. Usually when you install the JDK, these files will be installed anyway usually in `\lib\src.zip`, which is stored in your JDK install directory. For me it was `F:\Library\Java\jdk1.10.0_1\lib\src.zip`

Comment: when you are calling add() function, then super class methods of AbstracltList are called itself and they may contain print statement

Comment: In your example, any call to an abstract method in `A` will invoke the overriding method in `B`. It is important to understand that abstract classes (interfaces) and abstract methods _must_ be defined somewhere. So when you call a method in `A`, its not really `A` since `A` is abstract and you can't have an instance of an abstract object. Deep down, that call to `A` is actually a call to `B`, or whatever the last method to override that abstract method that is available. Give [Abstract Methods and Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html) a read.

Comment: Right, but there were no calls to `get` or `size`. What you're saying applies to when I do something like `nestedClassObject.get(0)`, which will call the overridden `get` defined in `B`.  In this case, however, no calls to `get` or `size` have been made, so the corresponding overriding methods in `B` shouldn't run, but they do.

Comment: The difference between `AbstractList` and `List` is that `List` is an interface and _everything_ in it is abstract. With `AbstractList`, some methods are defined. So while some methods are abstract, others have implementations. So unless _everything_ in `AbstractList` is overriden, then there may be a call to code in `AbstractList`, which in turn may call methods that you overrided in `NestedClass`. In my opinion, trying to grasp abstraction with things like `List` and `Set` is too complex. You should probably work on something where you control the abstract class and the non-abstract class.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense and is what I think @H.Tibat was saying in his answer. Thank you so much for helping me understand this part of abstraction.

Comment: @AisforAmbition FYI, Source file of any class(example `AbstractList`) can be viewed in an IDE provided it can find it or some may even dynamically create. For instance, in Eclipse, if you hold Ctrl key and move over a class/interface/method/member, it will enable that as a link and a click on it will lead you to same.

Answer (score 2):

That is the whole point of abstract classes/methods: your base class defines a set *A* of abstract methods, and a set *B* of non-abstract methods.

Now, most likely, methods out of set *B* will be calling methods from *A*.

In other words: you use an abstract class to **fixate** certain behavior (by writing methods out of the *B* bucket), but in order to allow for *different* overall behavior, you allow the user to implement *A* methods in different ways (by creating different subclasses, that implement the abstract methods differently).

Comment: How does that explain why they're running even when not invoked? You are just explaining why abstract classes are used.

Comment: @AisforAmbition The only way for a method to run is by being invoked. Again: **other** methods are calling them. You, or some part calls a(), which calls b(), which calls c(). I am giving you the big picture here.

Answer (score 2):

Method `public boolean add(E e)` in AbstractList has implementation which
calls `add(size(), e)`.

And also method `public Iterator<E> iterator()` relying on the backing list's `size()`, `get(int)`, and `remove(int)` methods.

Here is list of methods which rely on `get(int)`:

- indexOf
- lastIndexOf
- iterator
- listIterator

Comment: That makes sense that some other method(s) may rely on the 2 methods in question. Thank you, I hadn't considered that.